# Intermediate Fields and Root Fields

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, normal-extension

Suppose that $F \subset K \subset E$ are fields and $E$ is the root field of some polynomial in $F[x]$.  Show, by means of an example, that $K$ need not be the root field of some polynomial in $F[x]$.

I have tried many examples and I cannot come up with anything. I know some basic Galois theory. Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I think what you are calling a "root" field is more traditionally called a "spitting" field.  "Root field" makes me think of $k^{1/p}$.

Comment: The book I am using interchanges the terms "root field" and "splitting field." I learned root field first, so it was just more comfortable for me! Thank you for the input; I'll keep that in mind next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $F=\mathbb{Q}$, let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[4]{2})$, and let $E$ be the root field over $\mathbb{Q}$ of the polynomial $x^4-2$.

Then $K$ is not a root field over $\mathbb{Q}$, since the smallest root field over $\mathbb{Q}$ containing $K$ is $E$, and $K$ is a proper subfield of $E$ (all elements of $K$ are real, and only two of the roots of $x^4-2$ are real).